# randomly sample vector of tuples with weights in C++

Tags: c++, vector, random, tuples

I was wondering if somebody could help.

I'm looking for a fairly straightforward and ideally fast way of sampling from a vector of tuples with weights.

e.g. say I have a vector of tuples, each containing a value and a corresponding weight/probability:

```
vector<tuple<int, double>> foo = { {1,0.04},{2,0.8},{ 3,0.01 },{ 4,0.03 },{ 
5,0.1 },{ 6,0.9 } };
```

I want to go through foo and randomly sample based on the weights, so I would end up with a vector (either a new vector or replacing the elements in foo) that in this case, is problematically mostly going to be 2 and 6. e.g.

```
 vector<tuple<int, double>> bar = { {2,0.8},{2,0.8},{ 6,0.9},{ 6,0.9 },{ 
6,0.9 },{ 6,0.9 } };
```

I'm sure this is pretty straight forward using something like std::discrete_distribution, although I've yet to figure out exactly how.

Edit: 
Thanks for the help so far, I may have used some poor terminology with "re-sample".

In essence what I want is to take the vector of tuples "foo" as describe above, and produce a new vector "bar" which is the same size as foo, and made up of tuples from foo, but the tuples are randomly selected based on the probability weighting in the tuple. - hope that makes sense.

Comment: _re-sample_ what are you doing? What makes the values change?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want the output to be? I just can't understand from your question what you're asking (probably because I just lack domain knowledge of your terms).

Comment: I'm confused. Does the distribution change? Why did you say "re-sample" instead of "sample"? If foo provides the available choices and probabilities, then the actual result is completely different (and will not include any probabilities, just simple integers, what was choosen randomly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `std::discrete_distribution` would work. The following uses the weights to permute the vector of pairs. It tends to converge either to 2's or 6's as one might expect.

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const std::vector<std::tuple<int, double>>& v)
{
    for(auto&& i : v)
        std::cout << "{" << std::get<0>(i) << ", " << std::get<1>(i) << "}\t";
    return os;
}

auto permute(std::vector<std::tuple<int, double>>& foo)
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, double>> temp;              // return value
    std::vector<double> v;                                  // weights
    for(auto&& i : foo)
        v.push_back(std::get<1>(i));                        // get weights
    std::discrete_distribution<int> dd{v.begin(), v.end()}; // create distribution
    static std::random_device rd;
    for(size_t i{}; i < foo.size(); ++i)
        temp.push_back(foo[dd(rd)]);                        // build return vector by selecting from foo according to weights
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, double>> foo = {{1, 0.04}, {2, 0.8}, {3, 0.01}, {4, 0.03}, {5, 0.1}, {6, 0.9}};
    std::cout << foo << '\n';
    for(size_t i{}; i < 10; ++i) {
        foo = permute(foo);
        std::cout << foo << '\n';
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
{1, 0.04}       {2, 0.8}        {3, 0.01}       {4, 0.03}       {5, 0.1}        {6, 0.9}
{2, 0.8}        {5, 0.1}        {6, 0.9}        {2, 0.8}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}
{6, 0.9}        {2, 0.8}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}
{6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {2, 0.8}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}
{6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {2, 0.8}
{6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {2, 0.8}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}
{6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {2, 0.8}        {6, 0.9}        {2, 0.8}        {6, 0.9}
{6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {2, 0.8}
{6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}
{6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}
{6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}        {6, 0.9}
```

Comment: using `std::random_device` as the distribution generator ? I know it's formally ok, but is it a good idea ?

Comment: wait, I'm sure it's a bad idea, because there's no guarantee that the random_device effectively is non-deterministic ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I made the random device static. Is that what you meant?

Comment: that fixes one part of the problem; there's still the possible performance/quality issue of using a non deterministic source ... this is not explicitly said in the standard, but all sources I've read ( including the <random> author ) use random_device as a seeder only; I'd use a default_random_engine instead

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Addressing all the points you mention is [more involved](http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpps-random_device.html) than simply using the default random engine. The standard notes that `std::default_random_engine` is provided "so as to provide at least acceptable engine behavior for relatively casual, inexpert, and/or
lightweight use."

Answer (score 3):

Something like this ?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::discrete_distribution<> d({0.04, 0.8, 0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.9});
    std::map<int, int> m;
    for(int n=0; n<100000; ++n) {
        ++m[d(gen)];
    }
    for(auto p : m) {
        std::cout << p.first+1 << " generated " << p.second << " times\n";
    } 
 }

1 generated 2089 times
2 generated 42472 times
3 generated 544 times
4 generated 1631 times
5 generated 5473 times
6 generated 47791 times
```